# How to configure Spring boot app security using SAML Authentication with Azure AD

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, saml, spring-saml

Hi I am very new to spring boot security. Currently we are using LDAP(IdP) to authenticate the user in spring boot(SP) . Now we want replace LDAP with Azure AD using SAML authentication.

[SAML Integration with Spring Boot & Spring Security — Microsoft Azure AD](https://dummybot.medium.com/saml-integration-with-spring-boot-spring-security-microsoft-azure-ad-b9610bdb78b9)

Source code :
https://github.com/sravankadium/dummybot-example-saml

This above code is running perfectly. I have copied the setting but getting issue while hitting the end points in my project.

I have did some changes in my code .

Existing code:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final Environment environment;

    private final Ldap ldapConfig;

    public SecurityConfiguration(final Environment environment, final IccsConfiguration iccsConfiguration) {
        this.environment = environment;
        ldapConfig = iccsConfiguration.getLdap();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        if (developmentProfile()) {
            logger.warn("Enabling simple admin user for development purposes");
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("admin")
                    .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                    .roles(ldapConfig.groupToUpperCaseArray());
        }
        List<InetAddress> ldapServers = ldapConfig.getServers();
        for (InetAddress server : ldapServers) {
            String protocol = ldapConfig.isSecure() ? "ldaps" : "ldap";
            String port = ldapConfig.isSecure() ? "636" : "389";
            auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDetailsContextMapper(new InetOrgPersonContextMapper())
                    .userDnPatterns(ldapConfig.getUserDnPatterns())
                    .groupSearchBase(ldapConfig.getGroupSearchBase())
                    .groupSearchFilter(ldapConfig.getGroupSearchFilter())
                    .contextSource()
                    .url(protocol + "://" + server.getHostAddress() + ":" + port + "/");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizedUrl authorizedUrl = http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .requestCache().requestCache(new CustomRequestCache())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // Allow all Vaadin internal requests.
                .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
                .anyRequest();
        if (ldapConfig.groupIsDefined()) {
            authorizedUrl.hasRole(ldapConfig.groupToUpperCase());
        } else {
            authorizedUrl.authenticated();
        }
        http
                // Login page is accessible to anybody
                .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl(VaadinConstant.BASE_URL, true)
                .loginPage(VaadinConstant.BASE_URL + "/" + ViewConstant.Route.LOGIN)
                .permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl(VaadinConstant.BASE_URL + "/" + ViewConstant.Route.LOGIN)
                .failureUrl(VaadinConstant.BASE_URL + "/" + ViewConstant.Route.LOGIN + "?error")
                // Logout success page is accessible to anybody
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl(VaadinConstant.BASE_URL + "/" + ViewConstant.Route.LOGIN)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                // Create completely new session
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionFixation()
                .newSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/**/favicon.ico",
                // -- General=
                "/api/**",
                "/internal/**",
                // Client-side JS
                "/ui/VAADIN/**",
                // -- Swagger UI v2 --
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/swagger-resources",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                // -- Swagger UI v3 (OpenAPI) --
                "/v3/api-docs.yaml",
                "/v3/api-docs/**",
                "/swagger-ui/**");
    }

    private boolean developmentProfile() {
        return ArrayUtils.contains(environment.getActiveProfiles(), "dev");
    }
 }
```

After Edit:
SAML configuration:
SamlAppConfig.java:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.security.saml2")
@Configuration
public class SamlAppConfig extends SamlServerConfiguration {
}

@Configuration
public class SamlSecurityConfiguration extends SamlServiceProviderServerBeanConfiguration {

    private final SamlAppConfig samlAppConfig;

    public SamlSecurityConfiguration(SamlAppConfig samlAppConfig){
        this.samlAppConfig = samlAppConfig;
    }

    @Override
    protected SamlServerConfiguration getDefaultHostSamlServerConfiguration() {
        return samlAppConfig;
    }

}
```

SamlWebSecurityConfiguration :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SamlWebSecurityConfiguration extends SamlServiceProviderSecurityConfiguration {

    private SamlAppConfig samlAppConfig;

    public SamlWebSecurityConfiguration(
            SamlServiceProviderServerBeanConfiguration configuration, @Qualifier("samlAppConfig") SamlAppConfig samlAppConfig) {
        super("/saml/sp/",configuration);
        this.samlAppConfig = samlAppConfig;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.apply(serviceProvider()).configure(samlAppConfig);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfiguration:

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .requestCache().requestCache(new CustomRequestCache())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // Allow all Vaadin internal requests.
                .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();


       /* http
                // Login page is accessible to anybody
                .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl(VaadinConstant.BASE_URL, true)
                .loginPage(VaadinConstant.BASE_URL + "/" + ViewConstant.Route.LOGIN)
                .permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl(VaadinConstant.BASE_URL + "/" + ViewConstant.Route.LOGIN)
                .failureUrl(VaadinConstant.BASE_URL + "/" + ViewConstant.Route.LOGIN + "?error")
                // Logout success page is accessible to anybody
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl(VaadinConstant.BASE_URL + "/" + ViewConstant.Route.LOGIN)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                // Create completely new session
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionFixation()
                .newSession();*/


        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(GET, "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(GET, "/api/samlLink").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl(VaadinConstant.BASE_URL, true)
                .loginPage(VaadinConstant.BASE_URL + "/" + ViewConstant.Route.LOGIN);


    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/**/favicon.ico",
                // -- General=
                "/api/**",
                "/internal/**",
                // Client-side JS
                "/ui/VAADIN/**",
                // -- Swagger UI v2 --
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/swagger-resources",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                // -- Swagger UI v3 (OpenAPI) --
                "/v3/api-docs.yaml",
                "/v3/api-docs/**",
                "/swagger-ui/**");
    }

}
```

I know what is the problem but not able to solve , actually here I need to register `saml.discovery.url` and `saml.discovery.entity-id` and also `SamlProviderProvisioning<ServiceProviderService> provisioning`

There are so many example for Okta Auth but very few with Azure SAML .

Here I am not able to implement the SSO url , whenever I am hitting the localhost it is showing the forbidden error , and also I am not sure how to make entry point for SAML for my every request , my spring boot project uses Vaadin front end. I dont know what silly mistake am I doing , I am not sure how to proceed here. How can I make create entry url and whenever I am hitting any end point it should redirect the Microsoft login page.

Any lead would be appreciated Thank you !